# Potential Problem in "Swapping values of two variables without using a third variable"

Tags: c++, c, swap, operator-precedence

I recently came along this method for swapping the values of two variables without using a third variable.

`a^=b^=a^=b`

But when I tried the above code on different compilers, I got different results, some gave correct results, some didn't.

Is anything terribly wrong with the code?

Comment: Of course one wouldn't actually swap like that. Use a temporary, it's cleaner and executes faster on modern hardware.

Comment: I would say "I got different results" means that there is something terribly wrong with the code for all X such that X is "the code".

Comment: @GMan : Hmm, that's right. But it seems you are angry or something at someone, somewhere. :D

Comment: One shouldn't actually swap manualy with a temporary. in C++ exists a STL function called std::swap that does the same thing.

Comment: @Prasoon: I'm sick of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741051/couple-noob-c-questions) "I know Java/I know C#, trying to learn C++, in Java/C# we..." questions. The answer is stop and read a book. That's all. If you don't know beginner C++, you learn it by reading a beginner C++ book. There's no shortcuts there. Trying to guess around with "knowledge" from another language is like trying to fly a plane because you know how to ride a tricycle. That's stupid.

Comment: @GMan : Yeah right, stackoverflow.com is not(at all) an alternative to those really good books. One should read those books and then come and ask his/her doubts here. :)

Comment: @msw : `Swap` and `Code-Golf` tags were perfectly valid. I have often seen some beginner coders employing these (sort of) methods when they try implementing some basic algorithms which make use of bitwise operators.

Comment: So use your rollback privilege if you like, it is too trivial to warrant discussion.

Comment: Many, many duplicates, e.g. [Swapping two variable value without using 3rd variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826159/swapping-two-variable-value-without-using-3rd-variable)

Comment: @Paul : No, Pattrick's problem here is different. He is not asking about `Swapping two variable value without using 3rd variable`.

Comment: swapping in this manner would only work for integer values, use third values instead its cleaner and also in case of floating point values doenst cause any truncation

Comment: @All who have voted to close: As per my opinion this was not a duplicate because the question Pattrick asked what not `How to swap two variable values without using 3rd variable`, I have voted to reopen.

Comment: I agree that a question about "why doesn't *A* work?" shouldn't be closed as a duplicate of "How to do *B*?" with the solution being *C*.

Comment: @GMan: let me quote you a comment from a MetaSO user that i feel perfectly sums up what SO is for: "This is a question and answer site. Not a "complex question, insightful answer that grows you as a person site." People should be able to ask simple questions with simple answers, that just may so happen to be spoon-fed. A lot of people just want to write code that works. Not be empowered. – Owen Sep 19 '08 at 21:23"

Comment: @GMan: I'm not saying people shouldn't read the book, just that they shouldn't get yelled at for asking a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 38):

> Is anything terribly wrong with the code?

Yes!

`a^=b^=a^=b` in fact invokes Undefined Behaviour in C and in C++ because you are trying to change the value of `a` more than once between two sequence points.

---

Try writing (although not foolproof )

```
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

instead of `a^=b^=a^=b`.

**P.S** : Never try to swap the values of two variables without using a third one. Always use a third variable.

**EDIT** :

As [@caf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134633/caf) noticed `b^=a^=b` is fine even though the order of evaluation of arguments of `^=` operator is unspecified, since all the accesses of `b` within the expression are being used to compute the final value that is being stored in `b`, the behaviour is well defined.

Comment: The modification of `b` is actually OK, since it is read only to determine the new value (`b ^= a ^= b;` would be OK).

Comment: @caf : but the order of evaluation of arguments of `=` operator is unspecified.

Comment: @Prasoon_Saurav,Why do you tag the 3 statements as "not foolproof"?

Comment: @crypto : Because this swapping method would work only for integers. :-)

Comment: @Prasoon_Saurav, The operations are simply swapping the bit representation used for a & b, how would it matter if it were a different data type?

Comment: @crypto: the `^=` operator is not even defined for other types.

Comment: Do you mean that ^= is only defined for int types?

Comment: @Crypto : For `int` family. :)

Comment: This time it's also undefined for C++0x for the original expression. But `b ^= a ^= b` is actually fine in C++0x. The assignment to `b` is sequenced after value computation of `a ^= b`. The wording of C++03 is not clear in my opinion, but I'm not opposed to @caf's interpretation. I'm not going to bet on C++03 though :)

Comment: @Johannes : Thats for the information. I found C++-03 sequence points stuffs easier to read and understand as compared to terms like sequenced/unsequenced in C++0x. And as [R](http://stackoverflow.com/users/379897/r) said `a ^= ( a^=b , b^=a );` is also undefined in C++(and I am sure it would be well defined in C++0x). I'll miss good'ol sequence points :-)

Comment: @Prasoon well C++03's rules are too unclear to describe what really happens to `b ^= a ^= b` IMO. It looks innocent because the Standard says that it's fine to read and write the same variable in an expression if the read is to determine the value to write. This seemingly is the case in `b ^= a ^= b` or `i = a[i];` and similar. But there is no really strong wording in C++03 for this so I'm not going to bet, unlike for C++0x :)

Comment: @Johannes : But C++03 also says that the order of evaluation of arguments of `=` operator is unspecified. So you never know whether which side of the assignment operator gets evaluated first. :)

Comment: @Prasoon yes `a^= (a^=b, b^=a)` is definitely undefined in C++03 and C++0x => `a` is changed by `a^=b` (side effect) and value-computed by the left-most `a`, and both of these are not sequenced.

Comment: @Johannes : Damn! Now I am confused. You said that in `b ^= a ^= b`, the assignment to `b` is sequenced after value computation of `a ^= b` right? so that means in `a^= (a^=b, b^=a)` the assignment to left-most `a` is sequenced after the value computation of `(a^=b, b^=a)`, right? But hey, we have a comma operator in `(a^=b, b^=a)`, which would clear the side effect of `a^=b` then how would that be UB in C++0x?

Comment: @Prasoon it's UB for the above reason. `a = b` does not sequence the value computation of a relative to b. It doesn't matter whether `b` contains sequenced side effects of its own on `a`. They have to be sequenced relative to value computation of the left operand of `a = b` in order to be valid.

Comment: Remember we had a similar discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860461/why-is-i-i-1-unspecified-behavior/1860612#1860612).

Comment: @Johannes : Thanks for the precise explanation BTW.  :-)

Comment: The C++0x semantics has also been discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690141/multiple-preincrement-operations-on-a-variable-in-cc/3691469#3691469 . Now whether it's `^=` or `+=` doesn't matter.

Comment: @Johannes : Yeah, checked your answer again. Made sense, thanks. :)

Comment: `b ^= a ^= b;` is defined for the same reason that `i = a[i];` is defined.  It is true that `b` and `(a ^= b)` are evaluated in an unspecified order, but both must be evaluated before the new value of `b` can be calculated.

Answer (score 15):

If you're using C++, why not use the swap algorithm in STL? It is ideal for this purpose and it's very clear what it does:

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

// ...

int x=5, y=10;    // x:5 y:10
swap(x,y);        // x:10 y:5
```

Comment: To be fair, the question is tagged C as well.

Comment: @GMan: fair point! I've edited my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**Based on contributions from R. & sellibitze:**

Use the comma operator:

```
 (a^=b,b^=a,a^=b);
```

**From text & Wikipedia:**

*"The comma operator can be used to link the related expressions together. A comma-linked list of expressions is evaluated left-to-right and the value of the rightmost expression is the value of the combined expression. It acts as a sequence point."*

*"A sequence point guarantees that all side effects of previous evaluations will have been performed, and no side effects from subsequent evaluations have yet been performed. It removes the undefined behavior arising out of the unclear order of execution of the original expression."*

Comment: That doesn't help. The original statement is equivalent to yours, and both have undefined behavior.

Comment: I think the edited version should work because the comma is a sequence point.

Comment: I think it's still undefined behavior. It's equivalent to `a = a ^ (a ^= b, b ^= a);` and the lefthand size of the `^` operator could be evaluated either before or after the parenthesized expression.

Comment: The current version is defined. Still unwise though, as it is slow on modern CPUs by comparison with using a local temporary (which would of course be optimized to a register).

Comment: @R..:  The version is defined, since the comma operator has its own sequence point.  `a ^= b` is evaluated fully, then `b ^= a`, then `a ^= b`.  Since all of those are well-defined, stringing them together with comma operators is well-defined.  This doesn't apply to the similar-looking commas separating function arguments, of course.

Comment: @David: The answer has been edited again since my comment, which should be apparent from the content of my comment.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you use std::swap() for c++.

For c, use this macro. Notice that you need to compare a and b first, otherwise when they are point to the same memory location you will wipe out the value and it becomes 0.

```
#define swap(a, b)  ((a) == (b) || (a) ^= (b), (b) ^= (a), (a) ^= (b))
```

Comment: How do you figure on the ending up `0` when `a == b`? Initially, `a = b = X`. After `a ^= b`, `a == 0`. After `b ^= a`, `b == X`. Finally, with `a ^= b`, `a == X && b == X`. That's exactly what we expect.

Comment: @Novelocrat, I meant a special case when a and b are the same memory location, then you would wipe out the value. E.g. int a = 5; int &b = a; I edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: the solution would be to check (&(a)==&(b))

Comment: @flownt, sure you can do that, but even a & b are not pointing to the same address but have the same value, why even bother to swap?

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

Comment: There is a bug in this answer, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What about this one?

```
a = a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wondered why nobody suggested parenthesizing the expression. Seems it's not UB anymore.

```
a^=(b^=(a^=b));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following one also, but if to numbers are large enough value will overflow

```
a=a*b;
b=a/b;
a=a/b;
```