# Why is this statement not working in java x ^= y ^= x ^= y;

Tags: java, swap, undefined-behavior, xor

```
int x=1;
int y=2;
x ^= y ^= x ^= y;
```

I am expecting the values to be swapped.But it gives x=0 and y=1.
when i tried in C language it gives the correct result.

Comment: It's undefined behavior in C, since you're modifying both x and y twice in a sequence point.

Comment: Dont use it. Using an extra temp variable to swap 2 is MUCH more efficient because it doesnt have to make the computation.

Comment: @Imre: I will take your suggestion.

Comment: Behaviour of the expression `x ^= y ^= x ^= y;` is [undefined in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741440/potential-problem-in-swapping-values-of-two-variables-without-using-a-third-vari/3741450#3741450).

Comment: Sorry, that should read twice between sequence points.

Comment: @Matthew : Sorry I didn't see your comment before posting mine.

Comment: IMre L: you are completely wrong. Just because the "computation" takes longer for us humans, there is no reason to assume that it will take longer than an assingment on a computer. In fact, I bet both will take exactly as long. XOR is about the most trivial operation a CPU can do.

Comment: The wording "correct" is incorrect.

Comment: @ammoQ: Have you done benchmarking?

Comment: Imre: Yes, in C, gcc with -O3 optimization, identically fast.

Comment: In Java, assignments are faster.

Comment: Correction: in C,the ^= version appears to be a tiny bit faster on my computer, but it's on the edge of measurability.

Comment: The correct C version of what you are trying to do looks as folows `x ^= y; y ^= x; x ^= y;`. What you have in your original post produces undefined behavior. If it "works", it's only by accident. In reality, it *doesn't* work.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Your statement is roughly equivalent to this expanded form:

```
x = x ^ (y = y ^ (x = x ^ y));
```

Unlike in C, in Java the left operand of a binary operator is guaranteed to be evaluated before the right operand. Evaluation occurs as follows:

```
x = x ^ (y = y ^ (x = x ^ y))
x = 1 ^ (y = 2 ^ (x = 1 ^ 2))
x = 1 ^ (y = 2 ^ (x = 3))
x = 1 ^ (y = 2 ^ 3)             // x is set to 3 
x = 1 ^ (y = 1)
x = 1 ^ 1                       // y is set to 1
x = 0                           // x is set to 0
```

You could reverse the order of the arguments to each xor expression so that the assignment is done before the variable is evaluated again:

```
x = (y = (x = x ^ y) ^ y) ^ x
x = (y = (x = 1 ^ 2) ^ y) ^ x
x = (y = (x = 3) ^ y) ^ x 
x = (y = 3 ^ y) ^ x             // x is set to 3
x = (y = 3 ^ 2) ^ x
x = (y = 1) ^ x
x = 1 ^ x                       // y is set to 1
x = 1 ^ 3
x = 2                           // x is set to 2
```

This is a more compact version that also works:

```
x = (y ^= x ^= y) ^ x;
```

But this is a truly horrible way to swap two variables. It's a much better idea to use a temporary variable.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought an assignment returned true, which is why if statements where = was used instead of == always ran?
That'd mean your first statement was the same as x=x^true^true;

Comment: @Aaron, no.  JLS [§15.26](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.26): "At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of the variable after the assignment has occurred."  In Java, the old `=` instead of `==` in an `if` condition only compiles if the variable is a boolean.

Answer (score 15):

Mark is completely correct about how it evaluates in Java.  The reason is JLS [§15.7.2.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.7.2),  Evaluate Operands before Operation, and  [§15.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.7), which requires evaluation left to right:

It is equivalent (by [§15.26.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.26.2), Compound Assignment Operators) to:

```
x = x ^ (y = y ^ (x = (x ^ y)));
```

We evaluate left to right, doing both operands before the operation.

```
x = 1 ^ (y = y ^ (x = (x ^ y))); // left of outer 
x = 1 ^ (y = 2 ^ (x = (x ^ y))); // left of middle 
x = 1 ^ (y = 2 ^ (x = (1 ^ y))); // left of inner
x = 1 ^ (y = 2 ^ (x = (1 ^ 2))); // right of inner
x = 1 ^ (y = 2 ^ (x = 3)); // inner xor (right inner assign)
x = 1 ^ (y = 2 ^ 3); // inner assign (right middle xor)
x = 1 ^ (y = 1); // middle xor (right middle assign)
x = 1 ^ 1; // middle assign (right outer xor)
x = 0; // outer xor (right outer assign)
```

Note that it is undefined behavior in C, because you're modifying the same variable twice between sequence points.