# Why swap with xor works fine in c++ but in java doesn't ? some puzzle

Tags: java, c++, puzzle, swap, xor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is this statement not working in java  x ^= y ^= x ^= y;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844934/why-is-this-statement-not-working-in-java-x-y-x-y)

Sample code

```
int a=3;
int b=4;
a^=(b^=(a^=b));
```

In c++ it swaps variables, but in java we get a=0, b=4 why?

Comment: This should be avoided at such a high level: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Reasons_for_avoidance_in_practice

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By writing your swap all in one statement, you are relying on side effects of the inner `a^=b` expression relative to the outer `a^=(...)` expression. Your Java and C++ compilers are doing things differently.

In order to do the xor swap properly, you have to use at least two statements:

```
a ^= b; 
a ^= (b ^= a);
```

However, the best way to swap variables is to do it the mundane way with a temporary variable, and let the compiler choose the best way to actually do it:

```
int t = a;
a = b;
b = t;
```

In the best case, the compiler will generate *no code at all* for the above swap, and will simply start treating the registers that hold `a` and `b` the other way around. You can't write any tricky xor code that beats no code at all.

Comment: Note that "doing the XOR swap properly" doesn't work in the edge case that `a` and `b` are the same variable.

Comment: +1 for a more ideomatic way to swap variables.

Comment: How about this one statement: a = (b ^= a ^= b) ^ a;  Since side-effects are well-ordered in Java this should work.

Answer (score 7):

That's not guaranteed to work in C++ either. It's undefined behavior.

You should do it in three separate statements:

```
a ^= b; 
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

Comment: The reason being that not-strictly speaking between two sequence points(e.g. a ;) a variable may not change more than once, lest undefined behavior