# Bubble sort without using temporary variable

Tags: java

i want to sort both 1 Dimensional and 2 Dimensional array without using temp variable in java.
How to do it can anyone suggest

Comment: Why?  The temporary variable makes it much easier...

Comment: Use the old triple-xor technique.  (Of course, you still need temps for your array indexes.)

Comment: how about using a global variable?  ;)   bubble sort is predicated on storing nodes and swapping...

Comment: A) By not using bubblesort (unless that's your task specifically) B) you can't swap array elements without a temporary variable (unless it's an `int` or so and you want to do ugly looking xor magic http://stackoverflow.com/a/3912726/995891)

Comment: @abiessu it was asked in interview to sort without using temporary variable

Comment: Did you try anything or do any research? Your question is a little lacking..

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `integer`(numeric in general) array you can use the following element change approach in sort algorithm:

```
int x = 10;
int y = 23;

x = x + y;
y = x - y;
x = x - y;

System.out.println("x = " + x);
System.out.println("y = " + y);
```

output will be:

```
x = 23
y = 10
```

Comment: an array can contain number of elements....not possible to do it with this code Ashot

Comment: @user3182420, of course I know. But this is only the part of algorithm, when will be switched a[i] and a[j]. I wrote "you can use the following element change approach". The algorithm can select you (bubble sort) for example. You can find it here http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-program-to-bubble-sort and instead of using `swap` variable use provided approach.