# Why swapping integer variable by XOR doesn't work in a single line?

Tags: java, operators

I want to swap the value of two integer variables in java using the XOR operator.

This is my code:

```
int i = 24;
int j = 17;

i ^= j;
j ^= i;
i ^= j;

System.out.println("i : " + i + "\t j : " + j);
```

It will work fine but the following equivalent code doesn't work:

```
int i = 24;
int j = 17;

i ^= j ^= i ^= j;

System.out.println("i : " + i + "\t j : " + j);
```

Output is like this:

```
i : 0    j : 24
```

First variable is zero! What's wrong with Java?

Comment: What's wrong with `int k = i; i = j; j = k;`?

Comment: Java is fine, how r u ? :) Why do you need to use XOR ?

Comment: @Hbcdev: I know there are some simple ways for swapping. but my question is way two equivalent statement doesn't have same behavior?

Comment: @giorashc: I'm fine too ;) I just want to know the difference of that statements. I think They are equivalent but results are different

Comment: Not sure, but it seems like Java converts the expression to `i = i ^ (j = j ^ (i = i ^ j));`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844934/why-is-this-statement-not-working-in-java-x-y-x-y

Comment: @nhahtdh what's wrong about that conversion?

Comment: @Hachi: Since `^` is left-associative, value of `i` will be evaluated before the `(j = j ^ (i = i ^ j))`.

Comment: @nhahtdh okay that behaviour of java was new to me, thx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf) (Java 7 specification), *Section 15.26.2* (page 529).

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

According to *Section 15.7 Evaluation Order* (Page 423) (***emphasis*** mine):

> ### 15.7 Evaluation Order
>
> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right.
>
> #### 15.7.1 Evaluate Left-Hand Operand First
>
> The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated.
>
> ***If the operator is a compound-assignment operator (§15.26.2), then evaluation of the left-hand operand includes both remembering the variable that the left-hand operand denotes and fetching and saving that variable's value for use in the implied binary operation.***
>
> If evaluation of the left-hand operand of a binary operator completes abruptly, no part of the right-hand operand appears to have been evaluated.

Described in more details in *Section 15.26.2* (page 529):

> If the left-hand operand expression is not an array access expression, then:
>
> • First, the left-hand operand is evaluated to produce a variable. [trimmed]
>
> • Otherwise, the value of the left-hand operand is saved and then the right-hand operand is evaluated. [trimmed]
>
> • Otherwise, the saved value of the left-hand variable and the value of the right-hand operand are used to perform the binary operation indicated by the compound assignment operator. [trimmed]
>
> • Otherwise, the result of the binary operation is converted to the type of the left- hand variable, subjected to value set conversion (§5.1.13) to the appropriate standard value set (not an extended-exponent value set), and the result of the conversion is stored into the variable.

An example in the documentation

> **Example 15.26.2-2. Value Of Left-Hand Side Of Compound Assignment Is Saved Before Evaluation Of Right-Hand Side**
>
> ```
>   class Test {
>       public static void main(String[] args) {
>           int k = 1;
>           int[] a = { 1 };
>           k += (k = 4) * (k + 2);
>           a[0] += (a[0] = 4) * (a[0] + 2);
>           System.out.println("k==" + k + " and a[0]==" + a[0]);
>       }
>   }
> ```

So the expression in the question is re-written and grouped as:

```
i = i ^ (j = j ^ (i = i ^ j));
```

Left-hand operands are evaluated:

```
i = 24 ^ (j = 17 ^ (i = 24 ^ 17));
    **
```

Since the value of `i` is not "updated" as expected, it will cause the value of `i` to get 0 when `24` is swapped to `j`.

Answer (score 1):

By writing your swap all in one statement, you are relying on side effects of the inner `i ^= j` expression relative to the outer `i ^= (...)` expression.

[From the Java specificiation (15.26 Assignment Operators):](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.26)

> There are 12 assignment operators; all are syntactically
>   right-associative (they group right-to-left). Thus, a=b=c means
>   a=(b=c), which assigns the value of c to b and then assigns the value
>   of b to a.
>
> [...]
>
> AssignmentOperator: one of
>           = *= /= %= += -= <<= >>= >>>= &= ^= |=

You might want to consider the readability of the code. Perhaps it's best to e.g. put the code in a method called swap(), or do the actual swapping through the use of a temp variable:

```
int temp = i;
i = j;
j = temp;
```

Comment: But aren't evaluation of side effects well-defined in Java?  (Unlike C, for instance.)

Comment: Oli: Updated my answer, I hope it reflects a bit better now what I'm trying to say.Downvoter: Care to comment?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't think your quote from the standard addresses the question.

Answer (score 1):

The left-most `i` is being evaluated before it's changed.

You can instead do:

```
j ^= (i ^= j);
i ^= j;
```

Which is slightly less compact but works.

Comment: @nhahtdh's answer is more thorough than this.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing:
i ^= j ^ (j = j ^ i ^ j);

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little shorter solution compared to @nhahtdh . I know it's an old question but just wanted to document it on Stackoverflow :P

`i = i ^ j ^ (j = i)`