# Assigning a variable, what actually happens, Java

Tags: java, runtime, variable-assignment

In the following example what actually happens?

```
int a = 1;
a += (a = 2);
```

The output is 3, however I wanted to know what actually happens under the covers. 
For example i know that parentheses have higher priority to `+` so happening first (a = 2) the expression should become `a = 2 + 2`.
At runtime first the expression within parentheses should be executed and then a becomes 2. It seems that the first `a` on the left to `+` gets "loaded" before of `(a = 2)` and this last expression does not seem to override the previous loading.
In other words I am quite confused to what exactly happens behind the scenes.

If anybody knows, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324850/why-swapping-integer-variable-by-xor-doesnt-work-in-a-single-line/11325458

Comment: Same as `int a = 1; int tmpvar = (a = 2); a += tmpvar;`

Comment: It translates into `a = a + (a = 2);`, and operands are evaluated left to right.

Comment: BTW, it's a capital programming offense to actually use assignment in the middle of a statement like that.

Comment: @HotLicks ok but should not "parentheses ()" have higher priority and hence executed first?

Comment: Parentheses aren't executed.  Or evaluated.  Or anything.  They simply disambiguate association.

Comment: @Rollerball Take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the referenced example *15.7.1-2* from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.1, which is almost identical to the example you provided.  In particular:

> If the operator is a compound-assignment operator (§15.26.2), then
>   evaluation of the left-hand   operand includes both remembering the
>   variable that the left-hand operand denotes and fetching and saving
>   that variable's value for use in the implied binary operation.

Because of this precedence, the left hand of the += is evaluated first.

It might be confusing to you because of the parentheses, but note the section on parenthesis evaluation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.3, and in particular:

> The Java programming language respects the order of evaluation
>   indicated explicitly by parentheses and implicitly by operator
>   precedence.

In this case, the implicit precedence set by the += operator indicates that the left hand operand will be remembered per the spec.  While it's true that assignment operators, including "+=" have lowest precedence, the spec for += indicates that the left-hand operand will be remembered per 15.26.2.

Comment: actually the priority of += is the least and should be evaluated last

Comment: Please read the text of the example: In the following program, the two assignment statements both fetch and remember the value of the left-hand operand, which is 9, before the right-hand operand of the addition operator is evaluated, at which point the variable is set to 3.

Comment: This example is the same as yours, but with different numbers.

Answer (score 4):

From the JLS [section §15.26.2 Compound Assignment Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent
>   to E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1
>   is evaluated only once.

So for your example we have:

```
a = (a) + (a = 2)
```

With the expression evaluated left to right. Hence the output of 3

Comment: The statement you quoted doesn't say anything about the order of evaluation.

Comment: @rich.okelly ok so basically the left (a) gets put in turn in parentheses implicitly?

Comment: @nhahtdh It is inferred - the order of precedence is guaranteed by the ordering in the statement with brackets disambiguating statements.

Comment: @Rollerball Yes, but it doesn't affect the outcome of the statement. The brackets there are redundant. The right hand side of the `=` operator is evaluated left to right

Comment: @rich.okelly: By your line of reasoning, it is better to say that the order is guaranteed by the fact that all valid `op` are evaluated from left to right.

Comment: @nhahtdh Yes, I thought that the reason would be apparent once the expansion of the `+=` operator was stated. My bad!

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at the bytecode of the following program:

```
package A;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int a = 1;
        a += (a = 2);
    }
}
```

We just need to run this command:

```
javap -c Test.class
```

to get the following bytecode:

```
public class A.Test {
  public A.Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1           // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: istore_1
       2: iload_1
       3: iconst_2
       4: dup
       5: istore_1
       6: iadd
       7: istore_1
       8: return
}
```

---

## Explanation:

We will just focus on the two lines inside the main method:

```
int a = 1;
a += (a = 2);
```

[`int a = 1;` begins here]

```
0: iconst_1
```

- Pushes int `1` onto the stack.

```
-------------
|           |
-------------
|           |
-------------
|     1     |
-------------
    STACK
```

---

```
1: istore_1
```

- Pops int value from the stack to `variable 1` (`variable 1` represents `a`)

```
-------------
|           |             variable 1
-------------           --------------
|           |           |     1      |
-------------           --------------
|           |
-------------
    STACK
```

[`int a = 1;` finishes here]

---

[`a += (a = 2);` begins here]

```
2: iload_1
```

- Loads an int value from local `variable 1` and pushes it onto the stack.

```
-------------
|           |             variable 1
-------------           --------------
|           |           |            |
-------------           --------------
|     1     |
-------------
    STACK
```

---

```
3: iconst_2
```

- Pushes int `2` onto the stack.

```
-------------
|           |             variable 1
-------------           --------------
|     2     |           |            |
-------------           --------------
|     1     |
-------------
    STACK
```

---

```
4: dup
```

- duplicate the value on top of the stack.

```
-------------
|     2     |             variable 1
-------------           --------------
|     2     |           |            |
-------------           --------------
|     1     |
-------------
    STACK
```

---

```
5: istore_1
```

- Pops int value from the stack to `variable 1`.

```
-------------
|           |             variable 1
-------------           --------------
|     2     |           |      2     |
-------------           --------------
|     1     |
-------------
    STACK
```

---

```
6: iadd
```

- Adds the top two values together.

```
-------------
|           |             variable 1
-------------           --------------
|           |           |      2     |
-------------           --------------
|     3     |
-------------
    STACK
```

---

```
7: istore_1
```

- Pops int value from the stack to `variable 1`.

```
-------------
|           |             variable 1
-------------           --------------
|           |           |      3     |
-------------           --------------
|           |
-------------
    STACK
```

[`a += (a = 2);` finishes here]

---

```
8: return
```

- The main method returns.

---

## Conclusion:

`a = a + (a = 2)` is done through several operations. `2: iload_1` is executed as first command of `a += (a = 2);` which reads the first operand of the equation `a = a + (a = 2)` and pushes onto the stack.

Next, `3: iconst_2` and `4: dup` are executed which basically push int `2` twice onto the stack; one for loading it to `a` and the other as the second operand. After that, `5: istore_1` is executed which is loading `2` into `a` (`a = 2`).

Finally, `6: iadd` and `7: istore_1` are executed where `6: iadd` adds the first operand and the second operand and pushes the result onto the stack, and `7: istore_1` pops the result and loads it into `a`.

---

For simplicity, let's have a quick look at this code:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 3;
a += b;
```

and here is its bytecode:

```
public class A.Test {
  public A.Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1            // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: istore_1
       2: iconst_3
       3: istore_2
       4: iload_1
       5: iload_2
       6: iadd
       7: istore_1
       8: return
}
```

As you can see, it simply does the following:

- Loads int `1` into `a`.
- Loads int `3` into `b`.
- Pushes `a` then `b` onto the stack.
- Performs the addition on them and pushes the result onto the stack.
- Pops the result from the stack and stores it into `a`.